# Calling interface from pagedList Adapter - Android Kolin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to call an interface from a pagedList recycler Adapter in android kotlin ? Pleas ehelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the interface as an argument somehow, a way to do it is on the constructor

```
class YourAdapterImplementation(
    private val delegate: YourDelegateInterface
) : PagedListAdapter<YourModelClass, YourViewHolderClass>(
    yourDiffCallback
) {

    //... the rest of the mandatory code

   onBindViewHolder(...) {
       holder.someView.setOnClickListener {
           delegate.someMethod(...)
       }
   }

}
```

Then the instatiation is like this, probably on a fragment

```
class YourFragment : Fragment, YourDelegateInterface {

    onViewCreated() {
         //the view code
         val adapter = YourAdapterImplementation(this)
         recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    //the interface methods fully implemented
    override someMethod(...) {....}

}
```